# Reading using fstream character by character and passing the fstream to a function for further reading?

Tags: c++

Ok so I'm trying to open a file for reading and I want to read the first character only then depending on what that character is I send it to a given function. For example if it is a number, I send it to a function that continues reading to see if its just an int or a float.
I cant seem to figure out how to do this

```
void dummy(char dum, std::ifstream& fin){
    char test = dum;
    fin>>test;
    string simple = simple + test;
    simple = simple + test;
    ofstream outFile;
    outFile.open("output.txt");
    outFile<<simple<<"\n";
    return;
}


int main(int argc, char *argv[]){
    char c;
    //ifstream readFile;
    /*if(argc >= 1){
    readFile.open(argv[1]);
    }*/
    ifstream readFile;
    readFile.open("input.txt");
    readFile.unsetf(ios_base::skipws);
    readFile>>c;
    while(!readFile.eof())
    {   
        switch(c){
        case 'a':
            dummy(a,readFile);
        }
    }
}
```

it keeps throwing this error: Microsoft C++ exception: std::bad_alloc at memory location (location). Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: `string simple = simple + test;` does not make sense at all.

Comment: I want to take `std::ifstream::eof()` and throw it into a cold, dark ravine where no one without  a dozen-plus years of industry experience can find it.

Comment: 'dummy(a,readFile);' - did u mean to pass the variable 'c'?

Comment: Also I am unable to find any overloaded + operator in the string class which takes a string and a character as parameter as in 'string simple = simple + test;' and 'simple = simple + test;'. There is an overloaded += operator though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error is caused by this line:

```
string simple = simple + test;
```

Never seen this before, but my guess is you're concatenating a string that hasn't yet been initialised. Use this instead:

```
void dummy(char dum, std::ifstream& fin)
{
    char test = dum;
    fin>>test;
    string simple;
    simple = simple + test;
    ofstream outFile;
    outFile.open("output.txt");
    outFile<<simple<<"\n";
    return;
}
```

**Edit**: to read a set number of characters from a text file use the [istream::read](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/istream/istream/read/) method:

```
char test = '\0';
fin.read( &test, 1 ); // read one character into buffer
```

Comment: Thank you that worked to stop the error! Now it seems that fin>>test; does not read character by character.Do you know how to get it to only read a character

Answer (score 0):

you can open your txt file and give the first character by the code below!
the first character is in variable s.

```
#include <fstream>
#include <iostream>
#include <conio.h>
using namespace std;

void main (void)
{
char *s=NULL;
char str1;
ifstream file_txt("file_name.txt");
if (!file_txt)
{
cout << "sorry I cannot find txt file! ";
getch();
exit(0);
 }
file_txt >> str1;
s= &str1;
file_txt.close();
}
```